# CircleView с прозрачным фоном в mapObjects Yandex MapKit

Tags: yandexmapkit

```
circle = mapObjects.addCircle(
    new Circle(CIRCLE_CENTER, 750), Color.WHITE, 1, R.color.colorWhitetrans50);
```

По каким-то неведомым причинам цвет не меняется при прорисовки круга, я пытался менять цвет на красный, желтый или зеленый, в любых вариациях цвет всё равно остается одним, то есть при сборке проекта мои цвета карта отказывается принимать!

Answer (score 0):

```
mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().addCircle(new Circle(Now_Point, 750), Color.WHITE, 1, Color.BLUE);
```

Вот так всё работает, круг приобретает цвет, заданный последним параметром (в данном случае BLUE, то есть синий). Если задавать через `R.color` как у Вас, то тоже всё работает.